# Edit the home route to be parameterised in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-routing, angular-router

I am a newbie and just started to deploy parameterised routes in my angular6.

This is my home route in `app.module.ts`

```
const appRoutes : Routes = [ 
  {path:'', component:botComponent}
]
```

I would like to edit it as the following

```
const appRoutes : Routes = [ 
  {path:'/:bot/:code/:place', component:botComponent}
]
```

My goal is to have the URL like so `localhost:4200` at first, when you visit the app, and then, according to what is clicked, the URL may change to `localhost:4200/lianne/129/north` or `localhost:4200/jay/7/south`

but, with `{path:'/:bot/:code/:place', component:botComponent}` I get `Error: Invalid configuration of route '/:bot/:code/:place': path cannot start with a slash` in my console and I cannot see the app, just a blank page.

If I remove the first slash, and set it like `{path:':bot/:code/:place', component:botComponent}` then I dont get any error, but I still see a blank page.

How do I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you define parameters and don't pass them, you will end up with blank screen.
You need two routes like this:

```
const appRoutes : Routes = [ 
  {path:'', component:botComponent},
  {path:':bot/:code/:place', component:botComponent}
]
```

Now, improvisation is up to you, but as you can see, if your parameters are optional, you need a path for each of the combination.